# How to make AngularJS render variables inside custom attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, it seems that doing `{{value}}` inside things like `value=""` or `class=""` works fine, but doing something like:

`$scope.bar = "1234";`

```
<my-directive foo="{{bar}}" />
```

causes the string `{{bar}}` to be passed to `myDirective` rather than the string value of `bar`.

How can I force the value of `bar` to be passed instead of `{{bar}}`?

Comment: just use `<my-directive foo="bar" />`

Comment: Consider looking at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives

Comment: @sza I'd then have to create an isolate scope in the directive, right? so that's not an option.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm familiar with the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify an isolated scope in the directive, you don't need to pass a scope variable in - the directive will just get the inherited scope and you can reference:

```
scope.bar
```

If you want to isolate the directive scope and pass in the variable as an attribute you will need to do that in the directive initialization.

```
scope: { foo:'=localFoo' }
```

then in the directive you can reference 'localFoo' as the evaluated result of {{bar}}.

Comment: If I just do `scope.bar` from the directive, then the directive will be closely coupled with the variable name `bar`. If I wanted to change the variable to something else, the directive won't work. I simply want to be able to pass on the value of the string to the directive.

Comment: Then you will have to isolate the directive scope and pass it in as an attribute. Use the scope object in the directive and do a two way binding on it.

Comment: No, because in some cases I won't have a variable to pass to the directive, I'll just have a string that I'll type in. In other cases I will have a variable. So the only way to make it work in both cases is to pass in the string value of the variable.

Comment: You could have an 'override' attribute on the directive that you look at first and if its populated you use the string value of that by binding it with '&'. Otherwise, you use the two way binding.

Comment: How would I do that? The scope variable is instantiated out of the controller and link functions (to whom the attributes are available)?

Comment: Can't you declare the bindings in the directive and in the link function, check if the alternate attribute is populated? If it is, use it. If not, use the two way binding. The link function is where you want that value, no?

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but in the 2nd directive's template, I'm calling a 3rd directive to whom some of this info will be passed. So, I'll have to create these override methods in both directives, as well as any future ones which rely on this method. Its not too nice of a solution. There really should be a way to force AngularJS to just render the string value.

Comment: Angular will, but it sounds like you want it to decide between either evaluating the bound variable or interpreting it as a string. I don't know of a way to do that without this workaround. Also, if you declare a controller in the directive, you can share data between them without resending it. Maybe that would work also.